# Silverlight 4 Drag and Drop Performance

Tags: silverlight-4.0, drag-and-drop, silverlight-toolkit

I implemented a Silverlight page that allows me to drag a control to a handful of drop targets using the [Drag and Drop](http://themechanicalbride.blogspot.com/2009/08/new-with-silverlight-toolkit-drag-and.html) support in [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/).  The results are perfect.

Unfortunately, when I increase "a handful of drop targets" to the 130 drop targets required by the application, there's a 1-2 second pause from when I attempt to drag to when the drag image shows on the screen.  From that point, dragging and dropping is fast.

It's apparent that the large number of drop targets is causing the initial lag.  Can anything be done do reduce the lag?

It's possible to rework the UI to show fewer drop targets, but that would diminish the usability (also, even down around 30 drop targets, there's still a noticeable lag though not as bad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer... turns out there's a user submitted patch to Silverlight Toolkit in the comments of this post:

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/5165

Works like a charm!

Comment: How did you manage to apply the patch? I am having the same problem because of the number of drop targets. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't recall the exact steps anymore.  Did you try downloading the source attached to the post and working with that?

Comment: Yeah but I'm using Silverlight 5 so I tried getting a newer version of the toolkit but I couldn't compile it. I'll do some more research and try and think of something. Thanks anyway